# How to pass Jenkins 'file' parameter value to downstream pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am looking for solution to pass a 'file' (.csv) parameter value to downstream job. I have tried with below code but its not working.

```
    build job: "DownstreamJobName",
                            parameters: [
                                string(name: 'Releases', value: "1.2.9"),                                   
                                [$class: "FileParameterValue", name: "test.csv", file: new FileParameterValue.FileItemImpl(new File(env.WORKSPACE/env.filepath))],
                                string(name: 'UserEmail', value: "testemail")
                                ]
```

When I got researched got below link that there is an existing defect with file for Jenkins pipeline, dont know whether it got fixed or not. https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-27413

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this like below

```
propertiesFilePath = "${env.WORKSPACE}/test.csv"                                       
parameters: [
[$class: "FileParameterValue", name: "test.csv", file: new FileParameterValue.FileItemImpl(new File(propertiesFilePath))]                                   
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).